# Exposed date filter doesn't work with 'greater than' or 'less than' and 'is equal to'

Tags: 8, views

I'm working on a Drupal 8 site where I use a exposed filter to filter on date. I created a simple version of what I want on simplytest.me.

In this example I created a article with a start and end date.

```
Start date is 28-02-2018 01:00:00
End date is 28-02-2018 10:00:00
```

I also created a view with two exposed filters to filter on date range.

```
Exposed filter 1: >= Startdate
Exposed filter 2: <= Enddate
```

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

When I add *28-02-2018* in both filters the result is null. When I look in the query, I see it says *2018-02-27* instead of *2018-02-28*

What is going wrong? It looks like it doesn't see the *is equal to* part of my filter.

> [image]

Is this normal? How do I make this filter work as I expect?

I tried to fix it with https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2627512#comment-12382345, but this only adds an hour, not a full day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine helped me out, the problem was me not adding time to the search query. I found this already along the way in finding a solution but I didn't understand it at that moment. Now I do.

By not entering a time in the search field (so searching for 28-02-2018) the search will go to 28-02-2018 00:00:00 which is the same as 27-02-2018 23:59:59.

So what I had to do was search for 28-02-2018 23:59:59 instead, when entering this in the search field, the right items do show.